# How can React Js make a Border-botom as a function?

Tags: reactjs, styles, border, styled-components

I would like to give Border-bottom as a function. What should I do?

This is the code that Border-bottom should appear.

```
import React from "react";
import { Header } from "../BaseLabel";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const Header = ({ location: { pathname } }) => {
 const getStyle = (path) => {
    return {
      color: pathname === path ? "#191919" : "#B6B6B6",
      borderBottom: pathname === path ? "#191919" : null,
    };
  };
return (
    <>
   <ShapMenu>
       <ShapLinks to="/covid19" style={getStyle("/covid19")}> //Link
           <Header title="코로나19" current={pathname === "/covid19"} />
       </ShapLinks>
   </ShapMenu>
    </>
   );
}
```

This is Header Styled-components

```
const ShapMenu = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  scrollbar-color: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
`;
const ShapLinks = styled(Link)``;
```

This is a reusable component code. This code is not only used on this screen because it is a reuse code.

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import styled from "styled-components";
import React from "react";

export const Header = ({ title, children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Title>{title}</Title>
      <Items>{children}</Items>
    </>
  );
};
Header.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.node,
  children: PropTypes.object,
};

const Items = styled.div``;
const Title = styled.div`
  margin-right: 14px;
  font-size: 20px;
`;
```

This is the style property that I want to give to the title.

```
border-bottom: 2px solid
      ${(props) => (props.current ? "#191919" : "transparent")};
    transition: border-bottom 0.5s ease-in-out;
```

Comment: Are you using react styled-components? If so then please update your question to include all relevant code. We need to see the `Title` component. [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Drew Reese I edited it.

Comment: What is the issue? Have you tried passing `current` prop that is passed to `Header` on to `Title`?

Comment: Border-bottom attempted at the title, but it does not apply. There's a property at the bottom that I want to apply.

`border-bottom: 2px solid
      ${(props) => (props.current ? "#191919" : "transparent")};
    transition: border-bottom 0.5s ease-in-out;`

The Link reflected the Color property, but not the Border-bottom property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS styled rules appear to be correct. You should pass the `current` prop from `Header` to `Title`.

```
const Header = ({ current, title, children }) => { // <-- destructure current
  return (
    <>
      <Title current={current}>{title}</Title> // <-- pass current prop
      <Items>{children}</Items>
    </>
  );
};
Header.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.object,
  current: PropTypes.bool,
  title: PropTypes.node
};

const Title = styled.div`
  margin-right: 14px;
  font-size: 20px;

  border-bottom: 2px solid
    ${(props) => (props.current ? "#191919" : "transparent")}; // <-- use current prop
  transition: border-bottom 0.5s ease-in-out;
`;
```

[image: Edit how-can-react-js-make-a-border-botom-as-a-function]

Comment: This code is not only used on this screen because it is a reuse code. So if you add attributes to this code, other screens will change.

Comment: @eeezkim I see. Sounds like this use-case is fairly specific then. The opposite of general reusability. Create a new, more specialized header component. Or perhaps expose out a `borderBottom` prop for any component to use.

Comment: ` borderBottom: pathname === path ? "2px solid #191919" : "2px solid #ffff",`

OMG, I solved it! Thank you for thinking with me.